# How to create an Installer using PyInstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have created a project and there are 5 Python files and a folder that contains the photos I used in my project and now I want to make an Executable file and an installer using `PyInstaller`.

Maybe there is some way to create an installer of one python file but I have multiple Python files and a folder of photos which also needed to run the project properly. Can anyone explain to me how to do that or is it even possible with `PyInstaller` or not, if it's not then what should I try.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe try AdvancedInstaller?

Comment: Can you explain that to me? I never used that.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you had a file called `create.py` like:

```
def square (num)
    return num ** 2
```

Another file in the same directory called `input.py`:

```
from . import create
def take_input():
    x = input("Enter Input")
    return create.square(x)
```

And finally your `main.py`:

```
from . import input
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ip = input.take_input()
```

You will call the command:

```
pyinstaller --onefile main.py
```

And `pyinstaller` will import all the dependencies of all the files itself

Comment: Thank you but what about the folder in the same directory which has all the pictures I used in my project?